# Error: bad secret key size while converting base58 secret key to uint8Array format

Tags: solidity, web3js, solana

I am trying to convert my private key to uint8Array format. But I am getting "bad secret key size" error. Why? Here is my code:

```
const secretKey = bs58.decode("BxAN...RGM"); // secretKey: Uint8Array(32) 
console.log(Web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey));
```

It is a devnet phantom wallet address. I tried with different keys, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrectly passing the public key as an argument instead of private key. The correct syntax is:

```
Web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
```

Which caused `Error: bad secret key size`. You should pass the private key(in uint8Array format), not the public key.